# html linear gradient not stretching to all page

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set a linear gradient color as background of my HTML page, but when I apply the CSS style instead to stretch to the all page it repeat as you can see in the picture below.

How can I solve this issue and why?

[image: pic]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test BootStrap</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body class="body-page">

        Hello

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
.body-page{
    background-image: linear-gradient(blue,red);

}
```

Comment: My eyes _sting_ now... thanks...

Comment: don't watch and make constructive comments..

Comment: I'll rephase, then: _**please**_ change your gradient so it's less visually _painful_ to have on my screen - for the sake of everyone here with eyeballs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add `background-repeat: no-repeat;` and `background-attachment: fixed;`:

```css
.body-page {
  background-image: linear-gradient(blue, red);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<body class="body-page">
  Hello
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

you should use "background-repeat" , this will be your css file :

```css
.body-page{
    background-image: linear-gradient(blue,red);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
```